# inline style with if else

Tags: html, css, anchor

I want to have a inline style with if else ? is this possible.

```
 <p><a style="display:none" href="download.ashx?[pdflink]" target="_blank">Download</a></p>
```

this must be display none if [pdflink] IS NULL

Comment: Do you not want to use javascript or jquery?

Comment: What is the particular relevance to SQL?

Comment: This should really be handled by whatever templating system is populating that `[pdflink]`; it surely has some form of `if..else`.

Comment: by null you man "download.ashx?", "download.ashx?[]" or "download.ashx?[NULL]"??

Comment: What is [pdflink] exactly, which language you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

In the snippet below, an anchor tag href which matches `download.ashx?` will be hidden. So, if you have an anchor tag with additional content after the `?`, it will display.

```css
a[href="download.ashx?"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="download.ashx?[pdflink]" target="_blank">Download</a></p>
<p><a href="download.ashx?1" target="_blank">Download</a></p>
<p><a href="download.ashx?anything" target="_blank">Download</a></p>
<p><a href="download.ashx?" target="_blank">Download</a></p>
```